# pip not installing scrapy after previous attempts on windows

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install scrapy and other modules using pip and they failed to do so ,it using cached files from previous installations that i tried to install but the failed.How do i resolve this problem please. I'm running windows on my machine

[image: This is the image i'm recieving from the prompt when installing]

Comment: post the error message as text so that people with the same issue could find the question.

Answer (score 0):

The cached files are broken. Try to disable cache by `--no-cache-dir`